# How can I hide border lines of parent element when an element sits on top?

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the nested divs that are over layed, to hide the lines behind it. The patterned background will need to remain visible and aligned.

[How do I remove these overlapping lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv6W5.png)

[So it looks like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhQS1.png)

I have a background that has a pattern and although it would make it easy, removal of the background is unfortunately not an option.

Divs that are added will have position absolute, and will vary in size, and could be anywhere, although the parent div line will **always** go through the centre.

One solution I tried was to add the repeating background to the nested divs, but because of the `scroll` property, and the absolute positioning of the nested divs, the grid pattern won't match up.

This is the basic setup from the screenshot. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/markos84uk/pen/KKqLedo) is here too

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="block nested"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.background {
  height: '100%';
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-color: midnightblue;
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%);
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 29%;
  top: 29%;
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.nested {
  height: 200px;
  left: 25%;
  top: 20%;
}
```

Here is what I tried with the background pattern, and trying to make it line up, but when the canvas is resized, the pattern doesn't match up.

```css
.background {
  height: '100%';
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-color: midnightblue;
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 1px, transparent 2px, transparent 100%);
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 29%;
  top: 29%;
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.nested {
  height: 200px;
  left: 25%;
  top: 20%;
}
```

Comment: You can't. You have to add the background to your divs, but as you already wrote: If it's absolutely positioned it might look off. You could try and add a clip-path to the underlying div, but that doesn't sound too easy. And no guarantee it will work.

Comment: Put the div above the other div?

Comment: Thanks @cloned, yep, you're right. Had to go another route by changing the way the divs are built as to break them up. Thanks for your time replying.